# jQuery - If a database is updated, update the page

Tags: jquery, database, ajax

Righteo, Just started messing with Jquery, and I can update a database etc with it, but I want to know if there is a way to display new info posted into a database (even if it is not what was just posted) without a reload etc.

Don't write it out for me, just point me in the right direction... I want to pull it together myself.. best way to learn :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to poll to server periodically.

If you want the server to push to you, use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).

Answer (score 1):

```
 var dataString="variable="+variablevalue;
    // Check if there is any updates every 3 second.
    var x=setInterval(doUpdates,3000);

    function doUpdates() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "yourfile.php",
        data: dataString,                 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#yourid').html(data)
            //This will update the HTML code.
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way is to have the web page regularly poll the server for new info.

There is no way to initiate interaction from the server side.

**Edit:**

No way except to use a framework that handles the polling for your.

Comment: Would this be extremely bandwidth hungry?

Comment: Right, I might have to find an alternate method. I was working with a friend of on a project a while back and I cannot remember how it was done - He did all the AJAX while i did php... Maybe he just did refreshes and fooled me o.O

Comment: Yes, it's bandwidth heavy, so the longer you can spread out your updates, the better.

Comment: This need not be very bandwidth heavy. Typical usage will have polling run every 1-5 seconds at most (longer if 'immediate' notice isn't needed. A poll that finds no new data should only require a minute amount of bandwidth (the request is not probably under 1 KiB and the response is tiny).

Comment: Ah thanks Kris, I will give this a trial run and have a look how it goes, if its not that heavy then i guess it will do :D

Comment: @Kris, consider a site like MarketWatch.com, where the Dow, S&P, and Nasdaq are changing constantly and maybe tens of thousands of people have their browser just sitting there on the page. Imagine what the polling requests look like for that.