# Update page without trigger or event

Tags: php, jquery

I'm implementing a twitter like news system on my website. It loads all news items on page load with an ajax call fine. But how do I show a new item without having a trigger like a page load or a click on something? So when a new item is added to the database, It should automatically be added to an open page, like an auto-update or something.

Answer (score 2):

you can look into

`ajax polling`

`reverse ajax`

[`comet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

`server polling`

here is a useful link http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

**edit**

you can achieve the effect by using jquery alone below are some useful links

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/ajax-update-content-every-x-seconds.html

[Timeout jQuery effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316278/timeout-jquery-effects)

Comment: Beat me to it. However, @john has specifically asked that the updates coincide with updates to the db, and to do this we need to be polling (by any of its names given above) the server. If it was me I would just a short timer (setInterval) with a cache, but if john is set on making it automated then...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an event, you have to generate one. A common practise to archive this is to have a timer running on the client/browser which fires an event in certain intervals to generate ajax requests.

Here are a few jquery plugins which might help you:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

Some SO posts which are in a similar direction:

- [Use AJAX to watch SQL database for changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813353/use-ajax-to-watch-sql-database-for-changes)
- [jQuery - If a database is updated, update the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932249/jquery-if-a-database-is-updated-update-the-page)
- [Sending notification to the user on database change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521243/sending-notification-to-the-user-on-database-change)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. However I'm a bit worried about the load effects on the server the polling will have, so I maybe have to reconsider this. But thanks for thinking along :-)